# Databinding in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a data entry Winforms App in VS2010. Along with an Entity Data Model (.edmx) that is connected to a SQL Compact Database. In this database I have a table Ticket that I am trying to make an insert into.

On my form, I have all my controls DataBindings property setup and pointing to the correct fields in the database.

I am trying to take the values from the controls on the form and add one non-databound field and save the ticket.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                this.TS = new TicketService();
                Ticket t = (Ticket)ticketBindingSource.DataSource;
                t.DateEntered = Datetime.Now;
                TS.SaveTicket(t);
    }
```

I am getting an error with Converting the TicketBindingSource to the Ticket Object.

Anyone know how to do this conversion?

Thanks

Edit: I am not sure if I was clear enough on my issue, I do not believe this is uncommon. All I am trying to do is take the data from my databound controls, place it into a variable, add a non-databound data (e.g. t.DateEntered = DateTime.Now like in the example above) and then Save the data to the database.

I have done this in VB.Net, but VB.Net does this conversion from the DataSource to the Variable automatically. Here is the VB.Net code:

```
            Dim t = ticketBindingSource.DataSource
            t.DateEntered = DateTime.Now()
            TicketService.SaveTicket(t)
```

C# does not do this automatically, it throws an error.

Comment: "getting an error" does not tell us anything. Does it compile? Does it run? Do you get an exception? You need to tell us the error or message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what do you want exactly, but this is a very good example:

[Insert, Update and Delete using Entity Framework](http://felixcen.blogspot.com/2011/03/insert-update-and-delete-using-entity.html)

I hope help you.

Happy code !

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is a very good link, but does not help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your problem but these two lines do not make sense:

```
Ticket t = new Ticket();
t = (Ticket)ticketBindingSource.DataSource;
```

You create a Ticket and assign it to t.

Then, you immediately re-assign t to something else.  The Ticket you created is never used and gets garbage collected.

Comment: Sorry I have edited that. I am trying to get the ticketBindingSource into the Ticket Object